# Monitor Solr statistics with collectd

Tags: solr, collectd

We use collectd to collect most of our statistics about our servers and services running on them. Right now we are trying to get a unified monitoring system up with the same front end for all our statistics.

So far all I've found about monitoring Solr is separate applications for collection and displaying the data. As we already have most of our collection of data done by collectd, it would be preferable to us to also collect Solr data with collectd.

Does anyone know if there are existing implementations of Solr plugins or Solr exec plugins for collectd out there?

Barring that, is there a reason why you should use other tools to collect and view Solr statistics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the generic JMX plugin help you ? http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:GenericJMX

Solr JMX : https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJmx